# Disavow duplicate content that has parameters?

Tags: backlinks, url-parameters, disavow-links

Wondering if anyone can help? I'm doing a backlink audit, and it seems that there is duplicate content due to parameters. The website itself and content are fine but then people seems to be commenting in the comment box section on the backlink site, generating parameters loads of parameter url. Should I disavow the page with the parameter or ignore this?

Comment: Disavow links is for spammy links which you need to tell Google you are not responsible.     If the links are spam, you can disavow them whether or not they have parameters.   There is no way that disavow links is going to help with duplicate content.

Comment: How does commenting on the other site create links with parameters to your site?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use Google's disavow links feature unless you have a penalty from Google caused by spammy links.  [Google says](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en):

> We recommend that you disavow backlinks only if you believe you have a considerable number of spammy, artificial, or low-quality links pointing to your site, and if you are confident that the links are causing issues for you. In most cases, Google can assess which links to trust without additional guidance, so most normal or typical sites will not need to use this tool.

Instead you should implement URL canonicalization.    You should tell Google that the URL without the parameters is the correct URL.  There are two ways to implement it:

1. Redirect with 301 permanent redirects to remove any superfluous parameters
2. Put a [meta link rel canonical tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en#6) in the `head` of each page to tell Google what the correct and preferred URL is for that page.